# How do I pipe output from a continuous stream on a remote SSH server into local program

Tags: ssh, stream, pipe

I have a remote SSH Linux host producing a continuous stream of ADC data which I would like to analyze in real time on my local Linux host.
How do I best pipe the data into the program on my local host?
Thanks in advance for any tip.
H

Comment: Did you try to pipe it? Where are your problems?

Comment: If I doseq 1 1000 | ssh 192.168.1.4 myprogram

Answer (score 0):

If I do for instance 
seq 1 1200000 | ssh 192.168.1.4 myprogram
on the remote I get the data from seq into myprogram but this requires me to open a ssh terminal into the remote.
Now
ssh root@192.168.1.106 "seq 1 1200000 | ssh 192.168.1.4 myprogram"
works, but for some reason it becomes much slower.
What is the best way?
H